# command mount into crontab doesn't work in macOS

Tags: bash, macos, cron

I set a crontab for mounting a remote volume, if I run the following command it works

```sh
mount -t smbfs //<__username__>:<__password__>@<__remote_host>/<__remote_folder__> <myFolder>
```

but into a crontab it doesn't work

```sh
30 13 * * * /path/to/my/script
```

Comment: Check the environment — does the PATH when run by `cron` include `/sbin` (where `mount` is installed).  One likely problem is that the path does not include `/sbin`.

Comment: Note that the environment set by `cron` is usually not the same as is set in your login shell.  You may need to write the environment in the script as run by cron to a known location (maybe not `/tmp` on a Mac — at least, if you can't find the file in `/tmp` after the script has been run, put it in `$HOME/tmp` or somewhere, creating the directory if need be).

Comment: when I insert `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin"` into crontab file, it works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) just enter in the path `/sbin`

part of `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had all sorts of problems with crontab on Big Sur until I cleaned out

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/StartupItems
```

for an apparently unrelated problem. These were repopulated after a reboot, except the last, which you have to set up yourself.